# How to fix 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Tags: javascript

why am i getting this problem even though the VSCODE shows thaere are no errors in  code

```js
var person={
        firstname:"koushik",
        sayHi : function()
        {
            console.log("hello there "+this.firstname)
        },
        check : function()
        {
            console.log (this===person)
        }
    }
    console.log(person)
```

I expect the output of person object but getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

EDIT:
the key `firstname` has a syntax error while assigning the value, `=` instead of `:`

Comment: `firstname="koushik",` A key-value pair is separated by `:`, not `=`

Answer (score -1):

```
var person={
    firstname:"koushik",
    sayHi : function()
    {
        console.log("hello there "+this.firstname)
    },
    check : function()
    {
        console.log (this===person)
    }
}
console.log(person)
```

you can use this code.
what was the problem see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_colon_after_property_id

another tip: try running your code in the web console of firefox

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic. They are not useful - flag them for closure instead of answering.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var person = {
  firstname : "koushik",
  sayHi() {
    console.log("hello there " + this.firstname)
   },
  check() {
    console.log (this === person)
  }
}
console.log(person)
```

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic. They are not useful - flag them for closure instead of answering.

Comment: @Vermula Koushik You have put `=` instead of `:`